# Downloading Azure Blobs using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, azure

Quick question about downloading Blobs from azure storage.  I'm a little lost on how this works exactly, here's my code:

```
 Try
        Dim accountname As String = "macroqc"
        Dim accountkey As String = My.Settings.Storagekey1

        Dim creds As StorageCredentials = New StorageCredentials(accountname, accountkey)
        Dim account As CloudStorageAccount = New CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps:=True)

        Dim client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient()

        Dim container As CloudBlobContainer = client.GetContainerReference("smallequipment1certifications")

        Dim blob As CloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filenamelbl.Text)
        Using MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
            blob.DownloadToStream(MemoryStream)
            My.Settings.downloadsource = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(MemoryStream.ToArray())
            equipmentpdf.src = filenamelbl.Text
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Sorry an error has occured while opening your file: " & Environment.NewLine & ex.ToString, "Download Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
```

So I am getting an error when I run this which looks like: 
[image]

So when it uploads the file to Azure storage it saves blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri & blob.Uri.AbsolutePath to the database.  Am I going down the right path using this method to download the file? The Blobs are private do I need an SAS to download?  I am confused and am having a really hard time finding useful documenation on this!  Can someone help point me in the right direction please!!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Can you share what's the value in `filenamelbl.Text`? Does it have full URL of the blob?

Comment: filenamelbl.text is the full URL of the blob yes

Comment: So what it is, there is equipment entered into a table which is displayed in the datagridview each line you click displays all of the information in the text boxes etc on the form.  I would like to be able to click the open button and load the .pdf from azure storage into the pdf reader on the form (equipmentpdf.src)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because [`GetBlockBlobReference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682596.aspx) expects the name of the blob (and not the full blob URL) and it creates a URL based on that. Since you're passing the complete URL, it still creates a URL but includes the blob URL. If you put a breakpoint and check the `blob` object's URL property, you will see something like:

`https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/filename`

Since the blob by the name `https://accountname.blob.core.windows.net/containername/filename` does not exist in the container, you're getting a 404 (Not Found) error. Please provide just the file name in `GetBlockBlobReference` and things should work just fine.

Comment: Ah that makes sense and it did get rid of the error.  So here's a dumb question... When the file is downloaded to memory stream where does it go?  How can I save it as a file on say the desktop for instance?

Comment: You can just call `DownloadToFile` method on your blob object and write the blob contents to a file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.downloadtofile.aspx.